# 'NumberOfCharsWritten' could be '0': this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW' 22

Tags: c++

Im trying to write a console screen buffer, but i keep getting different errors pointing at the LPDWORD variable no matter what values i assign to it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    COORD cell{0, 0};
    LPDWORD NumberOfCharsWritten = 0;
    wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[80 * 30];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWriten = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        screen[10 * 80 + 15] = L'P';

        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, 80 * 30, cell, NumberOfCharsWritten);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fundamental misunderstanding of the `lpNumberOfCharsWritten` parameter in the `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a NULL pointer to `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()`, but the pointer needs to point to an actual `DWORD` instead.

Declare a `DWORD` variable and use the `&` operator to get a pointer to that `DWORD`:

```
DWORD NumberOfCharsWritten = 0;
...
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(..., &NumberOfCharsWritten);
```

Comment: the error is gone, thank you!

Comment: @Mefhisto make absolutely certain you understand why the error is gone. It's one of the most important concepts you will learn in C++ programming.